# Ajax Control Toolkit Calendar control not working in DetailsView EditItemTemplate

Tags: asp.net, calendar, ajaxcontroltoolkit, detailsview, edititemtemplate

I have a DetailsView with a bunch of EditItemTemplates. One of them has a text box that accepts dates. In order to make the form more user friendly I wanted to add an Ajax toolkit calendar control so the user can pick a date from the calendar. I keep getting an error when trying to load the page.

Parser Error Message: Unknown server tag 'ajc:Calendar'.

My register tag is correct.

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajc" %>
```

My EditItemTemplate looks like this. Nothing fancy.

```
 <EditItemTemplate>
       <asp:TextBox ID="txtGrantedDate" runat="server" Text='<%#  Bind("GrantedDate") %>' />
       <ajc:Calendar  PopupPosition="Right" runat="server"
              TargetControlID="txtGrantedDate"
              Format="MMMM d, yyyy" SelectionMode="Day"
              PopupButtonID="imgGrantedDate" ></ajc:Calendar>
       <asp:Image ID="imgGrantedDate" runat="server" Width="20px" Height="20px" AlternateText="calendar" ImageUrl="~/Images/calendar.png" />
 </EditItemTemplate>
```

Where might I be going wrong and are ajax controls even allowed in DetailsView controls?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well this was silly. In case you guys run into this issue the correct server tag for the calendar extender is

```
<ajc:CalendarExtender>
```

Not

```
<ajc:Calendar>
```

The reason for the confusion you ask? Well it turns out that the samples on the Ajax control toolkit contains the following:

```
<ajaxToolkit:Calendar runat="server"
    TargetControlID="Date1"
    CssClass="ClassName"
    Format="MMMM d, yyyy"
    PopupButtonID="Image1" />
```

You can take a look at it for yourself at:

[Ajax Control Toolkit Calendar Extender](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/Calendar/Calendar.aspx)

Expand the Calendar Properties section and you'll see the code I copied above.